# How do I load JSON files with NodeJS Script? - Need to read and upload all JSON files in a directory with a possible pause between the files

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, recursion

I have the following JavaScript that runs in NodeJS. It's a script to upload data via a NodeJS API. I am not very familiar with the NodeJS functionality. I need help in refactoring this code so it does the following:

- reads an uploads only the .json file extensions in the directory
- file extensions follow a set naming convention with a number at the end of each file
- I want to iterate through all of the .json files in the same directory and load them to the api - it could be as many as 2,000 files at once (less than 2MB per file)
- Is there a way to give the files like 30 seconds between loads?

I am not very familiar with NodeJS and loading functions, which is why I need help. Please let me know if I can clarify anything. I need to be able to specify the directory to read the .json files from.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

//function to post transaction
function postData (xactData) {

   var options = {
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: 8080,
      path: '/abc/def/ghi/jkl',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Content-Length': xactData.length,
         'Request-Timeout': "600000"
      }
   };
   // setting up the request
   var post_req = http.request(options, res => {
      console.log('statusCode: ${res.statusCode}');

      res.on('data', d=> {
         process.stdout.write(d);
      });
   });

   post_req.on('error', error => {
      console.error(error)
   })

   //post data
   post_req.write(xactData);
   post_req.end();
}

//read in file
try {
   const data = fs.readFileSync('./file/xyz.json', 'utf8');
   if (data) {
      postData(data);
   }
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err)
}
```